# Grep for searching two statements on the beggining and end of file

Tags: files, grep

I have a file where i want to use grep to find what lines begin with 'X' OR end with 'xpto'

I've got this, but it does not work.

```
grep [^X][xpto$] test.txt
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In this case(complex grep matches) I usually prefer `egrep` in case its is available on the system (no need to escape).

`egrep "^X|xpto$" test.txt`

Answer (score 0):

By giving `grep` a number of expressions, you may test for lines that matches any of them:

```
grep -e '^X' -e 'xpto$' <test.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, I got it.

```
grep '^X\|xpto$' test.txt
```

Comment: Note that using `\|` as alternation in a basic regular expression is not universally supported.  On many systems, your expression would only match lines with exactly the contents `X|xpto` (i.e. `\|` matches a literal `|`).